# Problem configuring MySQL on Linux Ming ("Unit is masked")

Tags: linux-mint, mysql

I have a Linux Mint 20.2. I installed MySql Ver 8.0.26 (20.4).

I got this message when trying to run:

```
mysql.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mysql.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
systemctl unmask mysql.service
service mysql start
```